# Swift: Keep assignment made in closure

Tags: swift, firebase, closures

Trying to keep a changed value outside a closure. Assigning `length` from a child in a Firebase database within the `observeSingleEvent()` call. However, after the function, `length`'s assignment is not kept for use in the for loop, the initial value is used.

Furthermore, I `append()` a bunch of `GMSMarker` Objects to the list `markers` but again the appends are not kept and the list is returned empty

How can I keep the assignments done in the closures. I know in C++ you can use `&` like `[&varName]` to pass by reference. Have not found something similar regarding Swift.

```
func loadMarkersFromDatabase(ref:DatabaseReference, node:String) -> [GMSMarker] {
        var markers = [GMSMarker]()
        var length:Int? = 1
        ref.child("Config").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                length = (value?["AcademicBuildingsLength"] as? Int ?? 0)
            })
        print(length!)
        for i in 0...length! {
            ref.child(node).child(String(i)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let building = value?["building"] as? String ?? ""
                let lat = value?["lat"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let lon = value?["long"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                marker.title = building
                marker.snippet = node
                markers.append(marker)
            })

        }
        return markers

    }
```

I have tried adding a closure block `[length]` like this but then get this compile error: `Cannot assign to value: 'length' is an immutable capture`

```
ref.child("Config").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [length](snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                length = (value?["AcademicBuildingsLength"] as? Int ?? 0)
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Closures are asynchronously executed on another background thread. Because of this, you cannot mutate variables outside of this block and may have to use completion closures. To accomplish what you want, you will can call another function within your closure:

```
func loadMarkersFromDatabase(ref:DatabaseReference, node:String, completion: @escaping ([GMSMarker]) -> Void) {
    ref.child("Config").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [length](snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let markers = myFunction((value?["AcademicBuildingsLength"] as? Int ?? 0))
        completion(markers)
    }
}
```

and then:

```
func myFunction(length: Int) -> [GMSMarker] {
    var markers: [GMSMarker] = []
    for i in 0...length! {
            ref.child(node).child(String(i)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let building = value?["building"] as? String ?? ""
                let lat = value?["lat"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let lon = value?["long"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                marker.title = building
                marker.snippet = node
                markers.append(marker)
            })
        }
    return markers
}
```

Comment: When calling loadMarkersFromDatabase(ref:node:completion) what do I put for completion? It's calling for a function that take a list of GMSMarkers and returns nothing.

Comment: You are right, you need to pass in a function that takes an array of GMSMarkers and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after the function, length's assignment is not kept for use
>   in the for loop, the initial value is used.

The modifications to `markers` are kept. The problem is you are making incorrect assumptions about the order in which things execute. You are assuming that the `loadMarkersFromDatabase` function returns "after" the closure executes, but that is not the case. The `observeSingleEvent` method does not execute the closure you give it synchronously, but keeps it around to execute later. (The fact that you need to pass a closure to it is a big hint of this; because it it were synchronous, it could just return the snapshot directly instead of passing it into your closure.)

If you put in logging statements in the two places, you can see the actual order in which they execute. When the closure runs, it will add elements to `markers`, and any other code that shares access to `markers` will see that change. But you are not making use of that because your `loadMarkersFromDatabase` function has already returned.